# Sinatra instance variables not evaluated in view following an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, sinatra

I've run out of ideas, and have canvased the web with no hint of a solution, so I hope someone can get me out of this mess because I'm really, really stuck.

One of my routes queries a databse and renders data through an erb via a bunch of instance variables (@campagnes and @missions). No worries there, everything works fine.

I've set up a jQuery function that helps me filter data on my table based on a dropdown selector. So if the user changes the selected value in the dropdown, the jQuery $.ajax method reloads the page, passing the selected value to the 'get' route.

Here's what I don't get. The call works, it's successful, the parameters are passed to the route, they are used to read from the database, BUT all the instance variables that have the new set of data REFUSE to be evaluated in the view. Instead, the old ones are still used (the ones that where evaluated with the initial GET, before the Ajax call) and therefore the table is still the old table.

What do I need to pass in my Ajax call for the instance variables to be evaluated again in the view?

Here's my route:

```
get '/admin/mission' do
# load the appropriate js file in template
@js = "mission.js"

# retrieve list of all campagnes, latest on top
@campagnes = Campagne.all :order=>:id.desc


if !params[:campagne]
#puts "camp id retrieved from normal GET"
camp_id = @campagnes[0].id # first campagne in collection is latest
else
#puts "camp id retrieved from ajax call"
camp_id = params[:campagne] # if submitted via Ajax
end

# retrieve list of missions for selected campaign
@missions = Mission.all :campagne_id => camp_id, :order=> :numero.asc

erb :admin_mission , :layout => !request.xhr?

end
```

My view (edited down to important stuff)

```
<div id="mission_form">
<form class="cmxform" name="mission" action="/admin/mission" method="post">
<ol>
<li>
  <label for="campagne" id="campagne_label" >Choisir une Campagne</label>
  <select id="campagne" name="campagne">
    <% @campagnes.each do |c| %>
      <option value="<%= c.id %>"> <%=h c.nom %> </option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
</li>
<li>
  <label for="numero" id="numero_label" >Num&eacute;ro</label>
  <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="" size="5"/>
  <label class="error" for="numero" id="numero_error">Champ obligatoire.</label>
</li>
<li>
  <label for="nom" id="nom_label" >Nom de la mission</label>
  <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" placeholder="" size="50"/>
  <label class="error" for="nom" id="nom_error">Champ obligatoire.</label>      
</li>
<li>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" class="button" value="Ajouter" />
</li>
</ol>  
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<table div="table_mission" id="hor-minimalist-a" summary="Main Table">
  <!-- Table header -->
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th scope-"col">Campagne</th>
  <th scope="col">Mission</th>
  <th scope="col">Briefing</th>
  <th scope="col">De-Briefing</th>

 </tr>
</thead>

<!-- Table body -->
<tbody>
<% @missions.each do |m| %>
<tr>
  <td>
    <%=h m.campagne.nom %>
  </td>
  <td>
    #<%=h m.numero %>: <%=h m.nom %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%=h m.briefing %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%=h m.debriefing %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span><a href="/<%= m.id %>">[edit]</a></span>  
  </td>
  <td>
    <class="meta"><%= m.created_at.strftime("Created: %m/%d/%Y") %>
  </td>  
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>  
</table>
```

And my script file (also edited to keep the important bits):

```
$(document).ready (function() {
// hide all error and confirm labels
// refresh  mission table if change campagne dropdown
$('#campagne').change(function() {
  var inputs = [];
  $(':input').each(function () {
        inputs.push(this.name + '=' + escape(this.value));
      });

  $.ajax({
    data: inputs.join('&'),
    url: '/admin/mission', // couldhave used: this.action if it was a submit...
    timeout: 2000,
    error: function() {
      console.log("Failed to submit"); // remove when going live
    },
    success: function() { // 

      $('label#campagne_confirm').show(function() {
            console.log("Sucess!");

          });
       }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance variables are only used to create the HTML / JavaScript view from your ERB template, so, without reloading the page, no amount of changing the values of those variables will affect what's already been rendered as a view.

Your Ajax call ought be returning whatever new data your page needs in a form that the JavaScript can then use to manipulate the page's DOM. Eg return a nice block of json constructed server-side.

Also you might want to look at [DataTables](http://datatables.net/), a nice jQuery plugin that helps manipulate table data. It has some nice Ajax handlers.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that should have been obvious but I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere :-) I started my Ruby journey with Sinatra, ActiveRecord, and jQuery as all new technologies I thought I'd learn at the same time and if you look at the sorts of questions I've asked here my learning curve seems  pretty typical. I've found it's useful to look at the rendered page as a trellis for the real view code (in javascript) that populates itself via AJAX calls to the API being served up from Sinatra whose helpers and routes read and write stuff to the DB via ActiveRecord (some prefer Sequel; 6 of 1, half dozen the other)

Answer (score 0):

Well after much hair pulling I have found a sort-of-solution (which I don't like much) and an explanation for the behaviour (though I'm not 100% certain).

Regarding the behaviour, my Ajax call does not refresh the page (which after all is the intended behaviour of Ajax) which explains why I couldn't see the new values.

I tried to find a solution via an Ajax post that redirects from my post route, but apparently the ajax post cancels the redirect in the post route (I have no idea why).

So in the end I just took an (ugly) ajax only approach that looks like this:

```
// refresh  mission table if change campagne dropdown
$('select#campagne').change(function() { 
//retrieve value from select tag
var camp_id = $('select#campagne').val();
// pass the parameter in the resource
var uri = "/admin/mission?campagne=" + camp_id;
// GET resource with parameter
// and pass the data returned (the page itself) inside an element
// with some filtering to only get the table from the page
$.get(uri, function(data) {
    console.log("get succesful");
    var $table = $(data).find('tbody');
    console.log($table);
    $('tbody').replaceWith($table);
    });

});
```

I'm sure there's a much better way to do this, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to have an entirely separate route for the campagne (campaign?) list, e.g.

```
def get_campagne_id
  @campagnes = Campagne.all :order=>:id.desc # you might want to cache this
  camp_id = if !params[:campagne] # personally I'd pass the params as arguments, but this will do...
    #puts "camp id retrieved from normal GET"
    @campagnes[0].id # first campagne in collection is latest
  else
    #puts "camp id retrieved from ajax call"
    params[:campagne] # if submitted via Ajax
  end 
end


def mission_by_campaign( camp_id )
  # retrieve list of missions for selected campaign
  Mission.all :campagne_id => camp_id, :order=> :numero.asc
end
```

Now this becomes:

```
get "/missions_by_campaign", :provides => :json do
  content_type :json
  missions = mission_by_campaign( params["camp_id"] )
  missions.to_json
end

get '/admin/mission' do
  # load the appropriate js file in template
  @js = "mission.js"

  camp_id = get_campagne_id

  # retrieve list of missions for selected campaign
  @missions = mission_by_campaign( camp_id )

  erb :admin_mission
end
```

Then you place ajax calls to /missions_by_campaign and use that to update the page.
There's more code you'd need to write, but it gives you an idea of what I'm talking about.